# I'm banned from asking questions for negative days

Tags: bug, status-completed, post-ban, rate-limiting

I was banned from asking question on stackoverflow, but the message that was provided to me told me to wait -18 days. Moreover, I thought that bans were only from 1 to 7 days?

Comment: If it’s a post ban, there is no time limit. Nevertheless, if you saw a negative time, that probably is a bug.

Comment: At least it was not -18 times square root of -1.

Comment: Post a snapshot of the message

Comment: @icktoofay SE has been implementing "rolling blocks" to get help to people who need it faster. Basically, you ask a few bad questions -> you can't ask questions for another day. You ask a few more bad questions -> can't ask questions for another few days... etc. [Read more here on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236568/breaking-down-question-blocks-lets-talk-about-rate-limits).

Comment: @hichris123 so does that mean OP was asking good questions?

Comment: @Louis for those who imagined they were banned?

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, then they complained but the SE staff squared things off for them. That's when stuff got real.

Comment: it's easy. UI is telling you to get back in time for 18 days to be able to ask questions again. [Time travels](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98014/165773) are a long known feature at SO

Comment: Negative days means that you're required to post for however many days or you'll be banned. It's like being sentenced to labor.

Comment: @Louis maybe I'm dense, but I don't get whats so special about `-18 * sqrt(-1)`. Why is `-18i` special?

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr -18 days is kaboom for the human mind. sqrt(-1) is kaboom for the computer. Computers lack imagination for imaginary numbers

Comment: Did your PC run into a blackhole or something?

Comment: Having a look at your profile there are very few questions in the 3 years that you have been a member.  I can only assume that a lot of them were deleted if you got banned.  Great for pointing out a possible bug, but should you not focus on getting your questions in line with the guidelines of the site so you do not get banned?  Unfortunately the fact  that you were banned makes you an unreliable bug reporter.

Comment: `Unfortunately the fact that you were banned makes you an unreliable bug reporter`, and here we start the vicious cycle. Unless someone gets banned, how can s/he face and thereby report this bug?

Comment: @Joop why would that make anyone an unreliable bug reporter?

Comment: Back to the future?

Comment: Oh come on, if you can't give us 1.21 g(j)igawatts, then you aren't _really_ trying now are you? (I kid, I kid, we're looking into this)

Answer (score 20):

Geoff has put in a fix for this, which will be in the next build.

The root cause was, [as usual](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/), caching. Folks who'd been rate-limited before were still getting the date for the end of their *previous* waiting period... Which, of course, tended to be in the past. Eventually, the cache would expire and you'd get the right number, but not until you'd invested serious time and money into building a time machine.

Sorry about that.